# Grammar of "how does your job go?"

Tags: present-tense, continuous

Is “How does your job go?” grammatically correct?

Comment: I don't think it's _grammatically_ incorrect, but most people would ask "How is your job going?"

Comment: It would depend hugely on what you mean to say. "How is your job going" idiomatically invites people to speak very generally about how they are enjoying their work, how they are progressing etc. It may depend who is asking, of course.

Comment: Please review uses of the present simple in English.

Comment: Can you edit to explain exactly what is puzzling you?